How to handle Sessions in a multi threaded initiator app?
I am writing a Spring Boot application that has a REST endpoint that takes a currency pair as input and responds with an exchange rate. I am planning to configure QuickFixJ as an initiator and use it to retrieve a quote. However I am unsure how to deal with Sessions. Do I define just one session section in my QuickFixJ config file (example config file below) and then use that single Session for all my REST requests? If so, do I need to use the single Session in a thread safe way?
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
SenderCompID=SENDER

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=TARGET


Are you using QFJ Spring Boot Starter?
https://github.com/esanchezros/quickfixj-spring-boot-starter
But regardless if yes or no, eventually you (or the starter) will end up calling Session.send() which can be called concurrently. It locks the outgoing sequence number until processing of one message is complete.
If you only have one FIX session, then you will only need to configure one session in your config file. If you have one or more sessions depends on against how much counterparties you want to connect to retrieve quotes.

Thanks @Christoph for the reply. This helped but I do have a couple follow-up questions. Will you expand on what "It locks the outgoing sequence number until processing of one message is complete." means? Are you saying Session.send() guarantees a duplicate sequence number won't be used? Finally, when you say "counterparties" is that equivalent to TargetCompID? So the number of sessions is equal to the number of TargetCompIDs?

Re seqnum: yes. Re counterparties: a counterparty is usually a distinct SessionID, that means a unique combination of FIX version, sender comp ID and target comp ID.

Thanks again @Christoph. I have one more follow-up regarding the sequence number. If I have multiple instances of the same Spring Boot app all connecting to the same counterparty do I need to use a MessageStore implementation that all instances of the Spring Boot app share? For example, the JdbcStore implementation. In other words, do I need to make sure the sequence number is not duplicated between the Spring Boot app instances since they are all using the same counterparty?

You cannot connect to the counterparty with multiple instances at the same time. This is forbidden by the FIX protocol. If you want to implement some sort of fail over or standby, then yes, you'll need to make sure that you have some sort of shared store. This could also be a file store on a shared file system.

Interesting. I promise I did read a good bit of the FIX protocol docs but this was something I didn't understand. That seems rather limiting to me but I am new to FIX so I am sure I don't understand that design choice. Thanks again!

Of course a counterparty could offer failover sessions with the same SessionID but a different host/port. But a FIX session is a point to point connection, so the same SessionID on the same host/port will only allow one connection at a time.
